# Removing Tooltip from Google Charts WordTree

Tags: javascript, css, google-api, google-visualization

I'm trying to remove the Tooltip from a [Google Wordtree Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree#events).

[image: See the tooltip on hover]

On the CoreCharts, there you can either set `enableInteractivity: false` or set the tooltip trigger to none:

```
tooltip:
  trigger: 'none'
```

However, this doesn't work for WordTrees, and those configuration options are not mentioned in the documentation. Furthermore, there is no `onmouseover` like the other charts that I could use to suppress further actions.

Can anyone think of a way I can hack together a solution? Here is a JSFiddle with an example WordTree:
https://jsfiddle.net/b70wrfoc/

Update: I'm fine with suppressing all javascript hover events on the parent div if that makes it easy.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it's not pretty, but it definitely does the job. My workaround was to put an overlay with 0% opacity over the top of the chart

**HTML**

```
<div id="wordtree_container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;">
  <div id="wordtree_explicit" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <div id="wordtree_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #wordtree_overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
  }
```